# Map FORM attributes to model in Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to delegate to Spring automatic mapping of HTML FORM fields to my model class. Is it possible?

I have a method:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=actionOne")
public void actionOne(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {    
}
```

This method processes the form submitting. And I want to create class like `Document` and I want automatic mapping of form fields to `Document` class. How to done this with Spring Portlet MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Spring form Tag.

Refer [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/).

And change your `Controller` appropriately

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=actionOne")
public void actionOne( (@ModelAttribute("document") Document document, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {    
}
```